# Pyrogram stops handle updates after "updatesTooLong" response

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, pyrogram, mtproto

I would like to write a bot that will listen to the specific chat and save messages to the local storage.
After starting the bot app, everything works properly, but after some time I can see such information in the logs:

```
pyrogram.client {
    '_': 'types.UpdatesTooLong'
}
```

Immediately after this log, my userbot stops hearing any message from any user.
How can I fix this and handle such case `updatesTooLong` ?

Comment: Does this help? https://core.telegram.org/constructor/updatesTooLong

Comment: Thanks, I saw this page, but I have no ideas how to use that with pyrogram

Comment: Seems like this  class should do it: pyrogram.raw.functions.updates.GetDifference

Comment: Well, but how can I handle updatesTooLong? It doesn't throws an exception or something else. It is just a record in the logs

Comment: @YaroslavHladkyi That's an update you get. You can set up a `RawUpdateHandler` and use an `if isinstance()` to check for `types.UpdatesTooLong`. Then you could call the method from the comments in that handler to get new updates again.

Comment: unlikely I can not handle this type with `RawHandler`...